# Getting empty value of a variable in laravel mail view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I've assigned public variables in the mailable. I'm getting some values of keys but  I get empty values from the keys that I had assigned later. I'm implementing queues as well.

**In my controller:**

```
public function changeOrderStatus(Order $order){

    $order->type = $request->type; //getting these two keys empty i.e.type and amount
    $order->amount = $transaction->amount;
    $mail = new CancelRefundOrder($order);

}
```

**In my /App/Mail/CancelRefundOrder.php**

```
class CancelRefundOrder extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $order;
    public $order_type;

    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;        
        $this->order_type = $order->type;        
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.ecommerce.cancel_refund_order_mail');
    }
}
```

If I `dd($order_type)` here I get the value. But in my blade cancel_refund_order_mail, I get empty value on `{{$order_type}}` or `{{$order->type}}` why?

Comment: Are you passing `$order` as a the model or as an id that belongs to the model ? Try `public function __construct(Order $order)`

Comment: $order as a model.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t want to pass the $order as an instance of Order Model, you can just pass the blade with order as a variable.

this would come under the your build methods

**public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.ecommerce.cancel_refund_order_mail')->with([ 'order' => $this->order, 'order_type' => $this->order_type]);
    }**

Comment: Hmm.. but the build model takes the class public property directly. No need to use `with`.

Comment: What if the order was an associative array, making it as an instance of Order would result in an error